# ¿Como puedo cambiar el texto de un TextBox con la barra espaciadora? (VFP)

Tags: formularios, validación, object

Tengo una pregunta con la que ojala puedan ayudarme.

Estoy haciendo un programa basico con **VFP 9.0** y quiero cambiar el texto de un **TextBox** con la *barra espaciadora*, me explico:

En un trabajo que tuve usabamos un sistema que al presionar la barra espaciadora en un campo, cambiaba de **DOLARES** a **PESOS** (anexo imagenes):

[image: Campo "PESOS"]

[image: Campo "DOLARES"]

Especificando mas detalles, he de aclarar que en ese campo **NO se puede usar ninguna otra tecla**, es decir, solo responde con la barra espaciadora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

intenta esto (Evento: **KeyPress** del textbox):

```
Local lc_LaTecla, lc_Divisa
lc_Divisa = alltrim(this.value)
lc_LaTecla = chr(nKeyCode)  
if inlist(LASTKEY(), 7)
do case
    case lc_Divisa = "PESOS"
    this.value = "DOLARES"
    case lc_Divisa = "DOLARES"
    this.value = "PESOS"
    endcase
return
endif

if !lc_LaTecla $ "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz " 
nodefault
endif

return
```

Hasta luego, espero sea funcional!.

Comment: Que tal, primero que nada, gracias por responder. Pero tengo una pregunta, en el codigo que me comparte, debo cambiar o sustituir algo, lo que pasa es que me marca error de sintaxis.

Comment: Saludos amigo, se me paso algo disculpa, por favor actualiza la línea del primer if: if inlist(LASTKEY(), 7) ......

Comment: Disculpa que pregunte de nuevo y encerio muchas gracias por la ayuda @marcosbuenos, pero ahora el error me lo marca aqui:  **Local lc_LaTecla, lc_Divisa lc_Divisa = alltrim(this.value) lc_LaTecla = chr(nKeyCode)**  Quizas tengo algo mal.

Comment: Actualiza this.value por thisform.textbox1.value. y establece la identación.
Local lc_LaTecla, lc_Divisa 
lc_Divisa = alltrim(thisform.textbox1.value)
lc_LaTecla = chr(nKeyCode)
if inlist(LASTKEY(),7) 
 do case 
   case lc_Divisa = "PESOS" 
       thisform.textbox1.value = "DOLARES" 
  case lc_Divisa = "DOLARES" 
        thisform.textbox1.value = "PESOS" 
  endcase 
  return 
endif

if !lc_LaTecla $ "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz " 
  nodefault 
endif
return

Comment: En el siguiente enlace te envio una captura del codigo en mi programa: https://sendgb.com/R5K14Wg6h80
Quizas sirva de ayuda para detectar que estoy haciendo mal

Comment: Saludos, la línea que te marca tiene que ir en 3 renglones; 1.- Local lc_LaTecla, lc_Divisa    2.- lc_Divisa = alltrim(thisform.textbox1.value)    3.-  lc_LaTecla = chr(nKeyCode)... intenta así...

Comment: Hola que tal, una disculpa por la demora en responder @marcosbueno. Te comento que logre hacer el codigo funcione, **solo cambie una linea del codigo que me enviaste, lo cual agredezco mucho**. La linea que cambie fue: `if inlist(LASTKEY(), 7)` por `IF nKeyCode == 32`. Pero ahora tengo un problema, ojala puedas apoyarme, es que al presionar una espacio pues deja... **un espacio en blanco antes de la palabra** y ademas no puedo cambiar a otro campo de texto con las flechas del teclado.